# How to save acceleration data in a file on my android device using python kivy?

Tags: android, python, kivy

I used jsonstorage and pickle but it did not work. Maybe I am doing it the wrong way? Activity appears and then disappears. The log says handler error. In the `update()` function value is storing to `txt` variable. I want to store this `txt` in to an external file on my mobile phone.

My code:

```
__version__ = '1.0' # declare the app version. Will be used by buildozer


from kivy.app import App # for the main app
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout # the UI layout
from kivy.uix.label import Label # a label to show information
from plyer import accelerometer # object to read the accelerometer
from kivy.clock import Clock # clock to schedule a method

class UI(FloatLayout): # the app ui
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(UI, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.lblAcce = Label(text="Accelerometer: ") # create a label at the center
        self.add_widget(self.lblAcce) # add the label at the screen
        try:
            accelerometer.enable() # enable the accelerometer
            # if you want do disable it, just run: accelerometer.disable()
            Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 2.0/1) # 24 calls per second
        except:
            self.lblAcce.text = "Failed to start accelerometer" # error

    def update(self, dt):
        txt = ""
        try:
            txt = "Accelerometer:\nX = %.2f\nY = %.2f\nZ = %2.f " %(
            accelerometer.acceleration[0], # read the X value
            accelerometer.acceleration[1], # Y
            accelerometer.acceleration[2]) # Z
        except:
            txt = "Cannot read accelerometer!" # error
        self.lblAcce.text = txt # add the correct text 


class Accelerometer(App): # our app
    def build(self):
        ui = UI() # create the UI
        return ui # show it

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Accelerometer().run() # start our app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use json store.it will surely work.
here is the code :
`Add import jsonstore
Jsonstore=(/storage/emulated/0/hello.json);
json.put(txt)`